# Bash jobs in the background

Tags: bash, shell, background, jobs

Is there a way to allow a background job in bash to modify variables? for ex:

```
[bash]# a=1
[bash]# a=2 &
[1] 14533
[bash]# echo $a
1
```

I'd like the value of a to be 2 not 1

Answer (score 4):

Variables can't be sent back to a parent process from a child, so what you're trying to do is impossible.  It's the same reason that `cd` has to be a shell builtin rather than an executable in its own right.  If it were an executable, it would run, change the directory, and then exit, leaving you back in the shell which hasn't had its directory changed.

Answer (score 1):

A child process can't affect his parent's environment, but if your background process ends after the evaluation you can "pass" the value as an exit code. The parent can catch it with the `wait` command. Here is an example of a background process returning a variable incremented by one:

```
etuardu@subranu:~$ a=1
etuardu@subranu:~$ (exit $[ $a + 1 ]) &
[1] 7486
etuardu@subranu:~$ wait $!; a=$?
[1]+  Exit 2                  ( exit $[ $a + 1 ] )
etuardu@subranu:~$ echo $a
2
```

Answer (score 0):

As Carl explained quite well, it is impossible.

An example:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=1
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
do
    let a=a+1 ;echo "Child value $a"
done &
sleep 2
echo "Parent value $a"
```

Output would show child with value 1-10, and then parent with old value of 1.

Answer (score -1):

```
-> a=1
-> a=2; exit &
-> echo $a
2
```

Comment: That is changing the value in the current shell not in the background, and then launching a subshell to execute the 'exit' command.

Comment: I don't like my solution but this works for the example of the user.

Comment: It doesn't. Nothing is modified in a background job.

Comment: Not in background, I mean in current shell. Look at the example of the user, he is not checking the value in the background process. He is checking the value in *current* shell.

If the user need the value in the current shell my example works (in bash 4.1). If he need check the value in the child process the example of @bbaja42 is the correct.

Comment: It doesn't actually work for me, the example above was a simple illustration, in my real script, there are 10 background jobs in parallel which do calculations and modify variables. They work in parallel in the background to save time, so transfer of information from background jobs to the shell is unavoidable.

Comment: Why don't use temp files? If you combine with tmpfs, it will be fast and you will can forget the bash variables.

Comment: Temp files is the first solution I originally thought about, however, I didn't want the overhead of creating and deleting files and I was for a more elegant alternative. I didn't know that time about tmpfs, it seems the only solution